# DocuSign API: Text and date in signed tab doesn't appear in DocuSign envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have a requirement to use the `document with PDF signature field` uploaded by the user and based on the user input, if he/she specify the signer name, I need to add the Text (Name of signer) and Date Signed tab below the signature field in the similar document.

We are using [Tab Placement Method 3: PDF Form Field Transformation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) as the type of documents we will be supporting is not fixed.

We are able to follow the documentation on DocuSign site and manage to send out document with signature.

**Issue:**

The challenge comes when we need to add in Text and Date Signed tabs. We are referring to [Tab Placement Method 1: Fixed Positioning](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) to achieve this. We are able to send the envelope to DocuSign but **unable to view the Text and Date Signed in the document**.

As there is no error return by DocuSign, we are unable to identify the root cause.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get help here if you post your code showing what you've tried thus far (rather than just expecting someone to provide the entire solution for you from scratch).

Comment: I am able to identify this root cause, it is due to the wrong parsing value type to x and y position of the tabs. They can only accept the integer value, while my code parse in double value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request that creates a Date and Text tab

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the agreement",
  "status": "sent",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
                "name": "jane doe",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "tabs": {
                    "dateTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "xPosition": "80",
                            "yPosition": "80",
                            "width": "80"
                        }
                    ],
                    "textTabs":[
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "xPosition": "80",
                            "yPosition": "120",
                            "width": "80"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Contract",
            "fileExtension": "txt",
            "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
        }
    ]
}
```